# ternary operator in python function argument to use default value

Tags: python

I have function with default values. Based on a condition I would like to either use a specified value or the default value. Example:

```
def f(a=1,b=2,c=3):
    print(a, b, c)
```

I would like to have the following logic:

```
if condition:
    f(a=4, b=5, c=6)
else:
    f(a=4, c=6)
```

But I would like to understand if it's possible to do this using a ternary operator e.g. something like:

```
f(a=4, b=5 if condition else <default value>, c=6)
```

Is there a way?

Edit for clarification:
I would like to tell the function to take the default value in case the condition is false without providing the default value in the if-else statement. So in the example above the output should be 4 5 6 if true and 4 2 6 if false.

Comment: @Cid I don't think it addresses OP's question since he's asking if that's possible to use `if`-statement in the default value for a function parameter, and to answer that, I don't think so.

Comment: i am aware of the ternary operator but I don't understand how it can be used to take the default value of a function

Comment: @Nik Not possible in any sane manner, just use the logic you have. Using conditionals in function arguments is generally not a very readable idea to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of would be:

```
func("arg", "arg2", *(("default",) if condition == True else ()))
```

Comment: Do not write `if x == True:`, this is a pleonasm. Write `if x:` which is the python way to do it as each object as a truth value.

Comment: I know. But this is just an example. I meant checking a condition there.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible as one liner. Named arguments are simply dict and default value is used when key is not present in dict.

So you can also write it as

```
if condition:
    f(**{"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6})
else:
    f(**{"a": 4, "c": 6})
```

kwargs approach is commonly used to add dynamic arguments

```
kwargs = {"a": 4, "c": 6}
if condition:
  kwargs["b"] = 5
f(**kwargs)
```

But I am afraid there is no single expression which put conditionally key into dict.